# Translation of seal script text (Poem identified: 元・譚處端《西江月・作伴修行未是》)

Tags: characters, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I've been trying to translate some seal script on a small piece a friend brought back from Japan. 
I've been using http://www.guoxuedashi.com/ and hanziyuan.net to guess them and think I ended up with this:
line 1: 佗伴像水来是XX
line 2: 物叱水XX雲XX
Line 3: 佺東氣何

Can anyone assist with the characters, and with a translation?

Thanks so much,

Dom
[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for making an effort, normally people don’t :(

Comment: It was actually fun - I learnt Japanese and did calligraphy so am familiar with seal script and radicals in general. But some of them are hard work!

Answer (score 2):

This is an incomplete text of the poem 《西江月・作伴修行未是》 by [Yuan Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_dynasty) poet 譚處端, produced verbatim from the image, detailed below:

> The text is split into columns from right to left as on the image, with pauses inserted at「//」. Characters inside parentheses（）indicate the modern equivalent.
>
> 1. ⿰亻（作）伴修行未是 // （飄飄）
> 2. 物外行持 // 孤雲野鶴
> 3. 任東㢴（西）// 何有些兒礙
> 4. 滯 // 淡飯（尋）他兩頓 // 清
>
> ---
>
> The rest of the poem is:
>
> 清淨淨無爲 //
>
> 寂寥瀟洒最相宜 //
>
> 別有一般滋味

My translation (roughly paraphrased):

> ### 元・譚處端《西江月・作伴修行未是》
>
> 作伴修行未是，飄飄物外行持。
>
> *The accompanying disciples' self-cultivating journey is incomplete, walking along the turbulent spiritual passages;*
>
> 孤雲野鶴任東西。
>
> *following the path of mysterious, recluse [sages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xian_(Taoism)).*
>
> 何有些兒礙滯。
>
> *What is there to stop their journey?*
>
> 淡飯尋他兩頓，清清淨淨無爲。
>
> *Finding scarce meals, [plain, simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cuisine#Other_restrictions), and [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei),*
>
> 寂寥瀟洒最相宜。
>
> *the balance of tranquillity and aloofness*
>
> 別有一般滋味。
>
> *has a sweetness of its own.*

Comment: quite strange, that the text is chopped after "清". and, the cloud patterns (雲紋) on the edge are slightly in different size :(

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 maybe its half of a two-part block...or maybe the craftsmanship just isn't that great :). Seal script writings tend to be subject to more mutilation because not many people can read them to tell that it's been cut off haha

Comment: Thanks for all of that Drooze! That's been very helpful :-)